# How to assert two values in selenium using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to selenium and trying to assert a value which should be greater than $100 could someone help me regarding the same. Thanks in advance.

Value: $700 need to verify this value is greater than $100 (constant value)

Answer (score 1):

Selenium Library by default has no Assertions, you can use either [TestNG's Assertions](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/6.8.17/org/testng/Assert.html) or
[Junit's Assertions](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13/org/junit/Assert.html)

Test NG / Junit Assert.assertTrue Examples :

```
int yourActualVal = 700;
final int yourConstantVal = 100;
Assert.assertTrue(yourActualVal > yourConstantVal, "Actual Value is not greater than the constant value");
```

or

```
if(yourActualVal < yourConstantVal)
 Assert.fail("Actual Value is lesser than the constant value");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assertTrue` assertion as following:

```java
Assert.assertTrue(actualValue > lowervalue);
```